# Filtering visual based on a list?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a visual that I need to filter it based on a list of values.

for example a line chart that will calculate all the customer IDs but not the IDs that are coming from a specific list. I tried to add the ID column to the filters pane and using the advanced filter select ( is not ) and picked the ID but the problem is that I have about 20 ID and some of them are not in the table yet.

So how can I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a custom visual - available via the Power BI Marketplace - that does exactly this:

**Filter by List**

Have a look at this short tutorial on how it works:

[Filter by List](https://blog.pragmaticworks.com/power-bi-custom-visuals-filter-by-list)